# Firebug lite on iPad

Tags: ipad, safari, firebug-lite

Already found this [page](http://community.godaddy.com/library/setting-up-a-debugging-environment-on-the-ipad/) with some helpful hints.

Problem is I need to debug a web application on a CMS using an iPad and Safari.
So far I haven't been able to make firebug-lite work. I am working in a secured environment having no internet acces, but can copy files using a USB-key.
I have copied `firebug-lite.js` to the local server and included the file in a script tag in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://my_server/js/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

Unfortunatly when I open the page in the CMS I cannot see the firebug-lite-button on the page. Verifying the source code firebug-lite should have been loaded on the page. There is no way to get a right click menu to inspect anything.

**What can I do to make firebug-lite work on the iPad? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: @Programmer: i am not asking for the Debugging Console, what i need is firebug lite

Comment: What does the [Debugging console](http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/14447/step-by-step-turn-on-the-iphone-ipads-web-debugging-console/) say?

Comment: @gioele: The Debugging console says nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start Firebug Lite already opened, as per http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Options :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="proto://path/to/firebug-lite.js#startOpened=true"></script>
```

I think you won't be able to inspect elements, but you can navigate to the elements in the DOM tree provided by Firebug Lite.

Comment: The solution is still valid. Just use the local install on  http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable on a server or path you have access to.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Firebug-lite has [problems with the iPad browser since late 2010](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/96d968fa3b16df71).

The problem ([ticket on official tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3443)) has not been yet solved.

Comment: i am using the latest Firebug Lite 1.4 (not 1.3.1 !). Did you test this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested the problematic page in Safari/Chrome/Chromium for desktop? Since they use Webkit, the same system used with mobile Safari/Chrome, you may be able to duplicate the error and find its solution. You can open Chrome's debugger with right click, Inspect element.

Comment: yes, the regular FF/Safari/Chrome browsers (on Mac/ Win OS) work fine with the site

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with the mobile version of the page? Did you try setting an iPad User-agent?

Comment: no, there is no ipad user agent nor a mobile version of the page